# Creating a passive sentence

Tags: expressions

Please help me make this a passive sentence. We couldn't go to our favourite restaurant because they were decorating it.

Comment: This is a question for the ELL site, not here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that

> We couldn't go to our favourite restaurant because it was being decorated